# New tag: "multi-classification"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification), which covers the more basic situation of two classes, but also that of *multiple* classes. The tag wiki is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification):

> Statistical classification is the problem of identifying the sub-population to which new observations belong, where the identity of the sub-population is unknown, on the basis of a training set of data containing observations whose sub-population is known. Therefore these classifications will show a variable behavior which can be studied by statistics.

However, we do get a number of questions on *multi-class* classification. [A simple search for "multi" in the "classification" tag currently returns 607 hits.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bclassification%5D+multi)

I am kind of wondering whether it would make sense to introduce a new tag like "multi-classification". Or "multi-class-classification", which sounds more correct but also more cumbersome - anything as long as the tag shows up when people start typing "multi". Or do we assume that simply searching for "multi" in the "classification" tag is enough?

Thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary.  We already have [multi-class](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-class) & [multilabel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilabel):

- `[multi-class]` Wiki excerpt: "Multiclass classification is a classification task in which there are more than two classes. It is also called multinomial classification." 387 threads, 237 with `[classification]`
- `[multilabel]` Wiki excerpt: "Multi-label classification where multiple target labels might be assigned to each instance."  162 threads, 82 with `[classification]`

Comment: Duh. I'm sorry, I thought I had looked for such a tag, but obviously I missed it.

Comment: No need to apologize, @StephanKolassa.  I found these because I already knew about them.